# drag and drop files from OS into JTable java

Tags: java, swing, file, drag-and-drop, jtable

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I was able to get drag and drop working with a regular panel but now trying with a table and I can't sort it out. I'm getting confused with the Points and DropTargets. Dont mind the "Add" button. I feel like I need to deal with the DnD first.

```
public class Table extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JButton add;
    private JFileChooser choose;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem file;
    private DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "File",
            "File Type", "Size", "Status" }, 2);

    public Table() {

        // String column [] = {"Filename ","File Type", "Size", "Status" };
        /*
         * Object[][] data = { {"File1", ".jpg","32 MB", "Not Processed"},
         * {"File2", ".txt"," 5 Kb", "Not Processed"}, {"File3", ".doc","3 Kb",
         * "Not Processed"},
         * };
         */

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(tm);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {

                Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);

                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
                List fileList = null;
                try {
                    fileList = (List) t
                            .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File f = (File) fileList.get(0);
                table.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, column);
                table.setValueAt(f.length(), row, column + 1);
                super.drop(dtde);
            }
        });
        scroll.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);

                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
                List fileList = null;
                try {
                    fileList = (List) t
                            .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File f = (File) fileList.get(0);
                table.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, column);
                table.setValueAt(f.length(), row, column + 1);
                // handle drop outside current table (e.g. add row)
                super.drop(dtde);
            }
        });

        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        file = new JMenuItem("file");
        menu.add(file);
        // menubar.add(menu);
        add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("lock_icon.png");

        add = new JButton("Add", icon);
        add.addActionListener(this);

        JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
        choose.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();

        int returnValue = 0;

        if (clicked == add) {
            choose = new JFileChooser();
            choose.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
                file.getAbsolutePath();

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Table t = new Table();

                t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                t.pack();
                t.setSize(600, 200);
                t.setVisible(true);
                t.setTitle("ZipLock");
                t.setIconImage(null);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally would ditch the drop target on the scroll pane, it's going to cause you to many problems.

Your drop method is a little queezy...

This is a bad idea....

```
List fileList = null;
try {
    fileList = (List) t
        .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
File f = (File) fileList.get(0);
table.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, column);
table.setValueAt(f.length(), row, column + 1);
```

Basically, you try and extract the file list from the transferable, and regardless of the success of the operation, you try and use it ?!  You do no validation of the returned value at all...

Your drop code generally doesn't really care about what column the drop occurred on, as you have name and size columns already, so I'd actually ignore that altogether.

As for the row, now you have two choices.  Either you add a new row when the user doesn't drop on an existing one or you reject the attempt.

### Reject drag's "outside" of table

(Or reject drags that don't call over an existing row)

To reject the operation while the user is dragging, you need to override the `dragOver` method...

```
@Override
public synchronized void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
    Point point = dtde.getLocation();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
    if (row < 0) {
        dtde.rejectDrag();
        table.clearSelection();
    } else {
        dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm been a little smart here (and not in the clever way).  Basically, if the user has dragged over a row, I've highlighted it.  This makes it a little more obvious where the drop is going.

In your drop method, I would also make some additional checks...

```
@Override
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {    
    Point point = dtde.getLocation();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
    if (row >= 0) {
        if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
            dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
            List fileList = null;
            try {
                fileList = (List) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                if (fileList.size() > 0) {
                    table.clearSelection();
                    Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                    model.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, 0);
                    model.setValueAt(f.length(), row, 2);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            dtde.rejectDrop();
        }
    } else {
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

### Accept Drag's "outside" of the table

The process is relativly the same, except now we can throw away the conditions that would have otherwise caused us to reject the drag/drop (obviously)

```
@Override
public synchronized void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
    Point point = dtde.getLocation();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
    if (row < 0) {
        table.clearSelection();
    } else {
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
    }
    dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
}
```

And the `drop` method

```
@Override
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {    
    if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
        List fileList = null;
        try {
            fileList = (List) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            if (fileList.size() > 0) {
                table.clearSelection();
                Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                for (Object value : fileList) {
                    if (value instanceof File) {
                        File f = (File) value;
                        if (row < 0) {
                            System.out.println("addRow");
                            model.addRow(new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("insertRow " + row);
                            model.insertRow(row, new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                            row++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

Note.  This will insert rows at the drop point, push all the existing rows down OR if not dropped on an existing row, will add them to the end...

**TEST CODE**

This a full running example I used to test the code...

```
public class DropTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DropTable();
    }

    public DropTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new DropPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class DropPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private JScrollPane scroll;
        private DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"File", "File Type", "Size", "Status"}, 0);

        public DropPane() {
            table = new JTable();
            table.setShowGrid(true);
            table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
            table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
            table.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);

            table.setModel(tm);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

            scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

            table.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
                @Override
                public synchronized void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
                    Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                    if (row < 0) {
                        table.clearSelection();
                    } else {
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                    }
                    dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                }

                @Override
                public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                    if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                        Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
                        List fileList = null;
                        try {
                            fileList = (List) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                            if (fileList.size() > 0) {
                                table.clearSelection();
                                Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                for (Object value : fileList) {
                                    if (value instanceof File) {
                                        File f = (File) value;
                                        if (row < 0) {
                                            model.addRow(new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                                        } else {
                                            model.insertRow(row, new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                                            row++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        dtde.rejectDrop();
                    }
                }

            });

            add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. the code is a little queezy but I was trying to just get the drag and drop working first. I'm still new to the DnD. As for the rows I want to have the drop become a new row. I thought that's what I was doing. How would I do that?

Comment: You'll need access to the table model.  Seen as you're already using a `DefaultTableModel` you can simply call [`DefaultTableModel#addRow(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: ok, Im confused a little. You're extracting the file from the dataflavor below where the new row is inserted? Shouldn't I pass in the fileList to the new row? Also what is this // Insert paranioa here...

Comment: and another thing which is out of my league. How do you have the file contents go into the right column. e.g how to put the file name under "File" the size under "SIze" etc..?

Comment: 1- yes, you should make the determination to insert a new row AFTER you've extracted file list; 2- paranoia is me saying that the checks may bit a little excessive, it's unlikely that you would receive an empty file list; 3- my example does (kind of) already do this (inserts the file name into the first column and the size into the third)

Comment: ok So I added a for loop to go over the selectedfiles but still no files are being dropped onto the table. Getting an error.  What am I missing here? I feel like I"m just putting in code and hoping it will work. 
`if (value instanceof File) {
File f = (File) value;                       table.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, 0);                      table.setValueAt(f.length(), row, 21);                      
for(File i: fileList)
{tm.addRow(new Object [i]);
}`

Comment: +1 good explanation. Though you fooled me a while, _talking_ about rejecting if not over an existing row and then _coding_ the drop to add a row :-)

Comment: thanks.helped me out a lot. It's still not dropping onto the table but I'm sure I can figure that out

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry, context of question changed, I will update my answer to be less confusion.

Comment: man thanks so much. I still can't get it to drop onto the table though. When I put the code in it throws a `The method drop(DropTargetDropEvent) of type Table must override or implement a supertype method`. I can take the `@Override` out but I have a feeling that's why the drop is not working.

Comment: Drop is a method overridden from DropTarget

Comment: do i need to be using both the "reject drags"code  and "Accept drags" code answers in your response? Because I'm only using the dragover and drop from "accepting drags outside the table." Sorry for being a pain, but I can't seem to work this out.

Comment: Use one or the other depending on your needs (I updated the answer to separate the two approaches)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for all your help but the code's not working. I'm going to mess around with it. I should be able to figure out what's going on

Comment: I thought maybe the error was from conflicting JRE or  compiler problems but it's not. Doesn't `(DropTargetDropEvent dtde)` take more parameters?

Comment: I've added a fully running example, which I used to test the code ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks so much!! You've helped me more than any tutorial. Can't thank you enough.