# JTable using Swings Drag and Drop Files

Tags: java, swing, file, drag-and-drop, jtable

I'm creating a MusicPlayer GUI which implements a Drag and Drop File onto the table which allows

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde){
            dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
            try {
                List fileList = (List)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                File f = (File)fileList;
                addDnDFile(fileList);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }

        }
```

As of right now I can't seem to figure out any possible way to convert a List into a File to be able to use my addDnDFile method which adds the file to my musicplayer.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }` Don't ignore exception output.

Comment: `for (Object o : fileList) {`...then check to see of `o` is an `instanceof` `File`...maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639804/drag-and-drop-files-from-os-into-jtable-java/13640115#13640115)

Answer (score 2):

A `List` is obviously not a `File`, it's a `List` of `File`s

Unfortunately, this was before we got generics ;), but basically, you want to iterate over the `List` and check that each entry is actually a `File` and deal with it in whatever manner you want, for example

```
@Override
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
        List fileList = null;
        try {
            fileList = (List) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            if (fileList != null && fileList.size() > 0) {
                for (Object value : fileList) {
                    if (value instanceof File) {
                        File f = (File) value;
                        if (row < 0) {
                            model.addRow(new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                        } else {
                            model.insertRow(row, new Object[]{f.getAbsolutePath(), "", f.length(), "", ""});
                            row++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

For a runnable example, you can check out [drag and drop files from OS into JTable java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639804/drag-and-drop-files-from-os-into-jtable-java/13640115#13640115)